# When fetching a model, all properties are null except for uid

Tags: typo3, extbase

I have an extension with custom tables, one of those I can't get to work. When I try to `findOneByUid()` from it, I seem to get the right record but except from `uid` and `pid` all properties have a value of `null`.

The name of the table is: `tx_myext_domain_model_advertisercategories`. I used to have an underscore between advertiser and categories, but it seems this is the way extbase expects it.

I have configured:

- ext_tables.php & ext_tables.sql
- \Domain\Model\Advertisercategories.php
- \Domain\Repository\AdvertisercategoriesRepository.php
- \Configuration\TCA\Advertisercategories.php

**I have uploaded these files to Github here:**
https://gist.github.com/kuipersb/4a5ef7f14ecc979866ae

The output I get when executing `findOneByUid()` or my custom method `searchAdvertiser()` is the following:

```
object(VENDOR\MyExt\Domain\Model\Advertisercategories)[334]
    protected 'advertiserId' => null
    protected 'name' => null
    protected 'uniqueCode' => null
    protected 'discount' => null
    protected 'uid' => int 1
    protected '_localizedUid' => int 1
    protected '_languageUid' => null
    protected 'pid' => int 2
    private '_isClone' (TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\DomainObject\AbstractDomainObject) => boolean false
    private '_cleanProperties' (TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\DomainObject\AbstractDomainObject) => 
      array (size=6)
        'advertiserId' => null
        'name' => null
        'uniqueCode' => null
        'discount' => null
        'uid' => int 1
        'pid' => int 2
```

But I would expect:

```
advertiserId: 2
name: Test
unique_code: test
discount: 10.00
```

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did it work with the code the extension builder created before you edited it? Do you get errors when you add records in the backend?

Comment: I have copied it as close as possible from the Extension builder's generated code for `Advertisers` and other models/repositories. In the backend adding records does not seem to work either.. I get an empty form.

Comment: Did you do the whole modeling process with the extension builder? The basic idea of this thing is that you don't need to copy&paste in the generated classes for the "basic" stuff any more, because everything should be created by the extension. Can you post a screenshot of the modeling pane in the extension builder with your extension loaded?

Comment: To be complete for future reference; yes all models where build using the Extension Builder except for this new model for categories. It was based on a copy of the Advertisers-model. I thought it would be quicker to copy some files and change the names.. need to be more careful next time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was in the `ext_tables.php`. The part that says:

```
'dynamicConfigFile' => \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::extPath($_EXTKEY) . 'Configuration/TCA/Advertisers.php',
```

On the end it should not be `Advertisers.php`, but `AdvertiserCategories.php`. One little typo.. :)

Thanks for your taking the time to investigate though Michael! It's alot of code I attached.

But the plural vs. singular names seems to be no problem. Although it would be better to go with singular names next time, I agree on that with you :)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have "adjusted " some things in the code yourself. The data type `\string` should just be `string` I guess. The model `\VENDOR\MyExt\Domain\Model\Advertisers` should (by naming convention) be named in singular, so just `\VENDOR\MyExt\Domain\Model\Advertiser` and the member variable of your class should just be `$advertiser` instead of `$advertiserId`.

When you put in an object in the code, TYPO3 will only write the uid into the field, so no need to name fields with `id` in the end any more.

Comment: I've have tried renaming to singular names, but that didn't change anything. I have however found the bug, and attached it as a new answer. Thanks for your time and critique though!